# I think there is a problem with the current way to get back asking privileges

Tags: discussion, feature-request, post-ban

I got question banned some time ago (I apologize for the poor quality of my questions) and so I decided to try to lift it by following the advice that have already been given on the site. So I first went back and edited my questions. And since apparently positive contribution to the site helps, I tried going to posts, editing grammar, answering to the best of my ability whenever possible and so on, and I actually increased my reputation a bit while doing so.

However in the process of doing so I learnt (or so I was told) that the main way to get the question ban lifted is by "losing" the negative weight on the poor questions that I made. The first step is obviously editing them to improve them, but then someone has to see them and upvote them (or eliminate their downvote) so that the weight goes up. However, if this is true, then there is a very anti-intuitive problem, old questions are very unlikely to be seen again, so even if you have improved them to a level where they would have gotten positive reputation had you first asked them correctly (which I should have done) they are unlikely to go up in reputation at all.

Shouldn't there be either a "revival" system for old questions, where, if they have been edited by the original author with the intention of improving their quality they get put into a queue (similar to new questions, but in a different place so as to not shadow legitimate first time questions) or another way to work towards a question ban lift?

I am not asking to get the ban lifted on its own, but I'd like some tools to work towards it getting lifted (i.e. I want to prove my worth).

Comment: Editing a post does bump that post to the top of its tag however I do find that upvotes can be hard to come by, especially if you're in a tag where very few questions actually do get upvoted so this system does fail those that are actually trying to sort their questions out.

Comment: I disagree, I am not asking what can I do. I am stating there is not enough for me to do and I want more options.

Comment: Although the few down voted questions probably need the most attention, the lack of upvotes on most of your question is probably the biggest concern. You should have payed attention when you received the warning message instead of continuing on the same track. Also the C/C++ tag followers are careful voters. You can ask a single question in 6 months. Make sure it is a great one.

Comment: Well if I cannot get the ban lifted in a week or so I'll just have to leave SO forever unfortunately. I kept going because I was given a huge task for a self directed course at university and I needed all the help I could get and SO was very helpful, but if it seriously takes 6 months to undo a mistake (or a series of mistakes) that are due mostly to the fact that I had too much "newbie" activity it seems SO is too draconic for my tastes.

Comment: @Makogan As a word of advice: If you rely on others solving the problems you have in your courses, you are lost already. Maybe you should reconsider your attitude towards your studies. If you have a question gerading your homework/assignments, the first person you should contact is your prof/tutor/teacher, not any online site! If there are permanent problem about a specific subject (e.g. C++ language), a good book about that subject might help, too.Online sites like, but not only, SO are far from providing usable answers in time. And SO is explicitly **not a tutoring site**.

Comment: It's also not a *help* site, and confusion over this is often what leads to this sort of frustration. The aims of the site are not to help you pass a course, but rather to create a repository of high quality questions and answers, and this is why both questions and answers are actively moderated by the community and why questions not felt to be helpful to future visitors are closed.

Comment: *I had too much "newbie" activity* It seems that it was that find request that did you in which, for what it's worth, is something I see higher rep users doing as well (though I have no idea why). To someone who's unfamiliar with the language, it looks like you mostly did a good job of turning that into something on topic. Just be sure you put enough code in the question itself to reproduce your issue. (You may have done this but the GitHub link makes me nervous.)

Comment: Yeah - some of your later questions don't seem that bad.  I found 'Can you map a C++ object to memory mapped peripherals?' at least interesting, unfortunately you got -3 for it, which I can't really understand, but accept as we have to do all voting;)   Nevertheless, the points made above about 'help for newbies' are very valid on a site for professional and enthusiast programmers - a set that requires, or at least implies, that users have  a reasonable basic knowledge already before posting questions here.

Comment: @Thingy Wotsit This is basically begging, but, if you found it interesting, doesn't that qualify for an upvote? :p

Comment: @MartijnPieters: How is a report that the current procedure for getting rid of question bans doesn't work a duplicate of the current procedure for getting rid of question bans?

Comment: @Joshua: because the procedure there is *what you are given*. There won't be other tools.